# how to post NSSystemDefined NSEvent

Tags: macos, cocoa, quartz-graphics, nsevent

I created a `NSEvent` and I want to post it. How can I do that?

It is a `NSSystemDefined` type and I want to post it globally. Basically some `IOHIDPostEvent` or `CGEventPost` equivalent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CGEventPost(0, [ev CGEvent])` does it.